# Trouble adding new list items on html tree with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a simple tree diagram where I can add items at the parent level, child level, and grandchild level. Currently, adding a parent item works properly. I am stuck trying to add a child item and haven't even been able to start the grandchild level. I was trying to just experiment with that and get it to add any item at the child level, but it's not working.

html

```
<ul id="addParent">
  <li class="root" class="add-child">
    <input /> <p class="add-child-field"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> New Child Tag</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input />  <p class="add-gc-field"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> New Grandchild Tag</p>      
    <ul> 
  <li><input /></li>
  <li><input /></li>
  <li><input /></li>
    </ul> 
  </li>
  <li><input /> <p class="add-gc-field"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> New Grandchild Tag</p>   </li>
  <li>
    <input /> <p class="add-gc-field"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> New Grandchild Tag</p>   
<ul>
  <li><input /></li>
  <li><input /></li>
</ul>  
  </li>
</ul>  
<div class="add-field"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> New Parent Tag</div>
```

jquery

```
$(".add-field").click(function() {
  $('#addParent').append('<li class="root" id="addChild"><input /> <p class="add-child-field" onclick="add_child();"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> New Child Tag</p></li>')
});

$(".add-child-field").click(function() {
  $(this).find("ul").append('<input />');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ppzo7opy/1/

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to use `.on()` because you create elements dynamically. Second `.find("ul")` is incorrect since this statement will try to find child elements of the clicked `<p>` and this is not what you want to do.

Here is fully working version: https://jsfiddle.net/ppzo7opy/4/

```
$(".add-field").click(function () {
    $('#addParent').append('<li class="root" id="addChild"><input /> <p class="add-child-field" onclick="add_child();"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> New Child Tag</p></li>')
});

$(document).on('click', ".add-child-field", function () {
    $(this).parent().after('<li><input /></li>');
});

$(document).on('click', ".add-gc-field", function () {
    if($(this).next('ul').length)
        $(this).next('ul').append('<li><input /></li>');
    else
         $(this).append('<ul><li><input /></li></ul>');
});
```

Comment: Only issue I noticed is that the grandchild inputs dont nest properly when they are a new set. It looks like they are nesting within the <p> tag

Comment: nevermind, figured it out. I just changed .append to .after to get it break it out of the <p>

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead:

```
$(".add-child-field").click(function() {
  $(this).append('<input /> <p class="add-child-field"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> New Child Tag</p>');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ppzo7opy/2/)